# Auto login in an iframe

Tags: authentication, iframe

I would like to authenticate the web app inside an iframe when it is loaded.

This is my code.

```html
<html>
<body>
<form id="login" target="frame" method="post" enctype="text/plain" action="http://localhost/v1/authentication">
    <input name='{"username":"johndoe","strongpass":"fewpagedevelop","captcha":{}, "trash": "' value='"}' type='hidden'>
</form>
<iframe id="frame" name="frame" src="http://localhost/" width="600" height="600"></iframe>


<script type="text/javascript">
    // submit the form into iframe for login into remote site
    document.getElementById('login').submit();

    // once you're logged in, change the source url (if needed)
    var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
    iframe.onload = function() {
        if (iframe.src != "http://localhost/home") {
            iframe.src = "http://localhost/home";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I get in the iframe is the `http://localhost/v1/authentication` response in JSON `{"token":"wefasdfasf..."}` and then just redirects to the `http://localhost/home.` How do I save the token to the session? Is there a backend method for this?

I believe my problem is that this is not a simple web app where logging in is a simple submit form. What happens is when I log in to the web app directly in `http://localhost/` and I check the network traffic, it sends a POST with the body `{"username":"johndoe","password":"strongpass","captcha":{}}` to `http://localhost/v1/authentication` and this POST returns`{"token":"wefasdfasf..."}`.

Any idea what this authentication is called? And how do I solve this?

Comment: you can pass that token to url and at /home parse URL to get it back, or you can store that token in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and get it back anywhere in you application

Comment: @LightNight the tricky part is I don't know how the webapp http://localhost/ checks if the session is logged in (like which localStorage I should store it to or how I will pass the token for it to understand). The webapp is a software I installed in my local machine.

Comment: oh wait. you have a login form, username and password, and have an iframe under that form, and you want to authorize that iframe with your login form?

Comment: Yes. I made the login form on my page to try and mimic their login form, but it doesnt work.